# can't persist entities on app engine using jpa

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

i am trying to persist two entities(with one to many relationship) using jpa but on persit it throws an exception 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :2`
i'm struck.

Comment: You mean the classes that you don't post ?, with the persistence definition that you don't provide ?, and the stack trace that you don't provide ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we're stuck too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a clean and build cycle removed the error and i am left wondering what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To late but it helps me, re-enhance the classes was the solition:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/9UIFOSF56kU